# Bar Chart Patterns in Legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend, groupplots

I have a groupplot with three bar charts using a common legend.  This worked great when I was using color, but now I have to prep for publication in black and white.  I'm not well versed at all in pgfplots.

I changed the bars from solid color fills to patterns, but I don't know how to produce a useful legend now.  Any help on how I could get the patterns into the legend is most appreciated.

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                    legend columns=-1,
                    legend entries={{\color{red}{\tiny Random}},{\color{blue}{\tiny ++Cost}},{\color{black}{\tiny ++FTE}},{\color{green}{\tiny ++Resources}},{\color{orange}{\tiny Hold All}}},
                    legend to name=CombinedLegendBar,
                    footnotesize,
                    group style={
                    group size=3 by 1,
                    xlabels at=edge bottom,
                    ylabels at=edge left,
                    xticklabels at=edge bottom}]
                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Empirical CDF}, xticklabels=\empty]
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=horizontal lines] coordinates {  (1, 6.886)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=vertical lines] coordinates { (2, 8.501)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=grid] coordinates {  (3, 10.179)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=dots] coordinates {  (4, 11.14)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=north east lines] coordinates {  (5, 15.001)};

                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Triangular CDF}, xticklabels=\empty]
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=horizontal lines] coordinates {(1, 6.886)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=vertical lines] coordinates {(2, 7.745)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=grid] coordinates {(3, 8.606)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=dots] coordinates {(4, 8.630)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=north east lines] coordinates {(5, 15.001)};

                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize LN/Exponential CDF}, xticklabels=\empty]
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=horizontal lines] coordinates {  (1, 6.886)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=vertical lines] coordinates {    (2, 8.428)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=grid] coordinates {  (3, 9.964)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=dots] coordinates {  (4, 11.087)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=north east lines] coordinates {  (5, 15.001)};

            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \ref{CombinedLegendBar}
        \caption{Triage++ Performance}
        \label{PlusPlusCombinedBar}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the option `ybar legend` explained in page 211 of the v1.12 manual to the axis options. You can also use the `area legend` option in the axis options, explained on the same page of the manual. Note that I had to load the `groupplots` library and set the compatibility `compat=1.12` in your MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                    legend columns=-1,
                    legend entries={{\color{red}{\tiny Random}},{\color{blue}{\tiny ++Cost}},{\color{black}{\tiny ++FTE}},{\color{green}{\tiny ++Resources}},{\color{orange}{\tiny Hold All}}},
                    legend to name=CombinedLegendBar,
                    footnotesize,
                    ybar legend,
                    % area legend, % This is the alternate option
                    group style={
                    group size=3 by 1,
                    xlabels at=edge bottom,
                    ylabels at=edge left,
                    xticklabels at=edge bottom}]
                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Empirical CDF}, xticklabels=\empty]
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=horizontal lines] coordinates {  (1, 6.886)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=vertical lines] coordinates { (2, 8.501)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=grid] coordinates {  (3, 10.179)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=dots] coordinates {  (4, 11.14)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=north east lines] coordinates {  (5, 15.001)};

                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Triangular CDF}, xticklabels=\empty]
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=horizontal lines] coordinates {(1, 6.886)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=vertical lines] coordinates {(2, 7.745)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=grid] coordinates {(3, 8.606)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=dots] coordinates {(4, 8.630)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=north east lines] coordinates {(5, 15.001)};

                \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize LN/Exponential CDF}, xticklabels=\empty]
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=horizontal lines] coordinates {  (1, 6.886)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=vertical lines] coordinates {    (2, 8.428)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=grid] coordinates {  (3, 9.964)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=dots] coordinates {  (4, 11.087)};
                    \addplot[ybar, pattern=north east lines] coordinates {  (5, 15.001)};

            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \ref{CombinedLegendBar}
        \caption{Triage++ Performance}
        \label{PlusPlusCombinedBar}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

`ybar legend`:
[image]

`area legend`:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much and my apologies for the missing elements of the MWE...novice mistakes.

Comment: No problem! Thank you for including an MWE at all - it made answering this question the work of moments and convinced me to answer; without the MWE you would not have an answer yet :-)

Comment: The area legend looks even better....can't believe I missed this in the manual...I swear I did look first :)

Comment: I agree, and I'm not sure the purpose of the `ybar legend` but it is (by the name) what's intended for `ybar` plots... Its a bit confusing, I think I first found the answer somewhere on here a while ago, which is how I knew what you were looking for :-)